# Ubuntu Asus VivoBook N580vd-fi038t keyboard issue

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I have a brand new Asus VivoBook Pro N580vd-fi038t, I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 before and it caused some freezing issues so I decided to downgrade the pc to the lts version but there are lots of functions shortkeys that doesn't work.
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just install [last kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) for ubuntu. I use 4.14 version.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.   Yous answer is very (too) concise. Could you provide more information as to how to proceed?

Comment: Hello, today Canonical rolled out new kernel with meltdown and spectre fix. It's new version is 4.13. So you just need `apt update` and `apt upgrade`